# Delphi REST Dropbox download file

Tags: delphi, api, rest, dropbox

Успешно получаю токен доступа, но никак не могу составить правильно запрос

Последняя попытка такая

```
  RESTRequest1.Method := TRestRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download';
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Authorization','Bearer ' + OAuth2Authenticator1.AccessToken);
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddHeader('Dropbox-API-Arg','{"path": "/Catcher.dat"}');
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('path','/Catcher.dat',pkGETorPOST,[poDoNotEncode]);
  RESTRequest1.Execute;
  local_filename := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'Catcher.dat';
  SomeStream := tmemorystream.Create;
  try
    SomeStream.WriteData(RESTResponse1.RawBytes,
      length(RESTResponse1.RawBytes));
    SomeStream.SaveToFile(local_filename);
  finally
    SomeStream.Free;
  end;
```

Выскакивает "400 Bad request"

В документации API DropBox написано составлять запрос так
https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation#files-download

В чем ошибка?

Comment: Похоже, что строка `RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem(...)` лишняя.

Comment: @zed Пробовал закомментировать, проблема осталась

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте перед execute , вывести строку куда нибудь, и попробовать перейти по ней в браузере, думается мне, Вы увидите проблему в URL'е.

Answer (score 0):

Я использовал ваш код для написания своей функции, с ней я смог получить файл в Dropbox с помощью `RESTRequest`. Это было слишком сложно сделать, но теперь код работает.

Вот мой пример кода, и надеюсь, он вам поможет:

```
try
  //URL de API do dropbox responsável por fazer upload do arquivo
  RESTClient1.BaseURL := 'https://content.dropboxapi.com/2/files/download';
  RESTClient1.FallbackCharsetEncoding := 'raw';
  RESTClient1.Authenticator := nil;
  RESTRequest1.Method := TRESTRequestMethod.rmPOST;
  //Parâmetro de autenticação (Key Authentication vinculada a conta do dropbox)
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Authorization', 'Bearer TOKENHERE', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
  //Parâmetro que informa aonde será criado o diretório no DROPBOX
  RESTRequest1.Params.AddItem('Dropbox-API-Arg', '{"path":"/app/imei.pdf"}', TRESTRequestParameterKind.pkHTTPHEADER, [poDoNotEncode]);
  SomeStream := TMemorystream.Create;
  RESTRequest1.AddBody('', TRESTContentType.ctAPPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM);
  TRY RESTRequest1.Execute; EXCEPT END;
  try
     SomeStream.WriteData(RESTResponse1.RawBytes, length(RESTResponse1.RawBytes));
     SomeStream.SaveToFile('C:\TEMP\imei.pdf');
  finally
     SomeStream.Free;
  end;
except
  on e:exception do showmessage(e.message);
end;
```

Comment: @mymedia Фразы "использовал ваш код" и "тогда я мог бы получить" - вы гугле транслятор использовали?

Comment: @0xdb, Яндекс Переводчик использовал. Вроде неплохой результат получился.

Comment: Хмм, что то первое предлоожение ну совсем не по-русски.